# Are there cases known of Big Sur bricking 15" inch MBP 2013 models?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, backup, software-update, big-sur

My parents have a 15" Late 2013 MacBook Pro. They would like to upgrade to Big Sur, which is still compatible with that Mac. On the internet, I've read several stories about 2013 MBP's that were unusable after updating. Some articles only named the 13 inch version, others talk about the 2013 MBP in general.

I can imagine that this has (almost) only happened to 13 inch versions, because they generally come with less power than the 15 inch version.

We'll of course backup it, but we want to prevent everything that brings along extra work.

Are there any cases of 15 inch MBP 2013 being bricked after updating to Big Sur, or has that only happened to 13 inch versions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Asking people to do some research for you doesn't work very well on AskDifferent, it also doesn't directly solve a practical problem. See the comments on the question linked to on top of your question for futher details.

Comment: Hi @nohillside I already did research, but I haven't found anything conclusive yet. Plus, I also saw the question about the 2014 MacBook Air. I'm asking if there are cases _known_ about this Mac, not if I should do it..

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade the question is rather theoretical :-) Also, if one lone user claims (or refers to) a botched MBP, does this prove anyting (or provide any actionable insights)? Botched upgrades could be caused by a lot of things, without further root cause analysis they are just anectotal. Apple claims compatibility but if your income depends on your MBP being usuable it's always recommended to wait for .1 or .2 of a major release before upgrading.

Comment: I _do_ want to upgrade, sorry if that wasn't clear. But I can't just ask for advice, otherwise it'll be marked as 'opinion-based'. So I'm looking now if there are many cases of a 15 inch  version known or if it only applies to 13 inch versions. Our income doesn't depend on the Mac, far from that ;-), but we would like to just update it, so that we have the most recent version of it (other Macs are already updated, this one is the oldest).

Comment: It’s really a case by case basis I think? However being myself on a late 2013 15” MacBook Pro, I have yet to have any issues on Big Sur 11.0.1, and I had upgraded on the first day it was released, with no installation problems. It’s run much more smoothly than I had expected, and I skipped Catalina altogether, previously being on Mojave

Comment: @AVelj thank you for sharing your experience!